# Adding a shade to camera in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Is there a possibility to set some param to camera or renderer, so everything on stage is seen in some shade, e. g. red? Like the "glasses effect". Without editing objects' materials. [image: pink shade]

Comment: You need to use [`postprocessing`](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing). Have a look at the source code of examples and write your own effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three option to get this effect:

**Method #1**

Apply a color to te light added to the scene:

```
Light( color : Integer, intensity : float )
```

**Method #2**

Pixel shader without alpha

```
vec3(red, green, blue)
```

Pixel shader with alpha

```
vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0)
```

**Method #3**

As mentioned above, you can use `postprocessing` to apply an already available shader:

```
var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.RGBShiftShader );
```